# css form checkbox styling with checked and after tags

Tags: css, cross-browser, pseudo-element, css-content

I am trying to design a form without using JavaScript or JQuery. It includes a series of checkboxes. The idea is to display a certain gif after the checkbox if it is unchecked. Otherwise, display nothing after it. This is the code I have:

```css
input[type=checkbox]::after
{
  content: url(images/unchecked_after.gif);
  position:relative;
  left:15px;
  z-index:100;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked::after
{
  content:"";
}
```

It works in Chrome but doesn't seem to be working in Firefox or IE. What is wrong?

Comment: `input` is an element with an empty content model – and since `::after` pseudo elements are rendered as child node of the element their are applied to, there’s a conflict. Some browsers allow to do it anyway – some don’t. Use the adjacent sibling combinator instead to format an element you put after the input element. http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#adjacent-sibling-combinators

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. But I am still unable to get it to work. For example, if I put a "p" tag after the checkbox, the following CSS selector doesn't work: 

input[type=checkbox]:checked + p:after

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cross-browser solution that worked for me was to include an empty label (with class "checkbox_label") after the checkbox input and then style IT rather than the checkbox.

```
input[type=checkbox] + label:after
{
  content: url(images/unchecked_after.gif);
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  top:1px;
  z-index:100;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after
{
  content:"";
}

.checkbox_label
{
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  left:20px;
  z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for answer can you provide some reference or what is + operator called...? in this.. context

Comment: [element1+element2 selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) selects the element2 that goes immediately after element1.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements is not supported by the specification. Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-input-elements). Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm testing in Firefox 20 and IE10, which is why I figured I was doing something wrong...but what?

Comment: I'm trying it out on jsfiddle with firefox and can reproduce your error. Let me see if I can find a fix.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. I've edited it into my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, wrapping the "input" in a "span" tag didn't work either. Darn, just gotta' keep trying different things I guess...

Comment: Hmm... Wrapping the input in a span tag worked for me. Are you sure that you are applying the `::after` styling to the span tag and not the input tag?

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. But what I did was added an empty "label" tag after the checkbox, and styled it as "height:0px; width:0px; display:inline-block; float:left; position:relative; left:20px; z-index:100;", and then used sibling selectors, like "input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after".

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5dRXg/

Comment: That JSFiddle didn't work in Firefox, and was malformed in Chrome. My solution seems to work fine in both. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: Ok, glad to help. BTW, that jsfiddle used text instead of an image because I didn't have an image to associate with it.