# :before not applying gradient to image?

Tags: html, css

I've been working on this for a while and I can't understand why it isn't working. In summary it's meant to just overlay a soft gradient over the image in the top left and right. However I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

```
<article class="main-home">
<div class="header">
    <div class="crumb">Placehold</div>
</div>

<div class="body">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="block_img"/>
</div>
```

and the css is also

```
article.main-home
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
article.main-home .body .block_img
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
article.main-home .body .block_img:before 
{
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , rgba(255, 0, 85, 0.2) 0px, rgba(255, 0, 85, 0) 25%);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've got an active jSFiddle here too: http://jsfiddle.net/J4Dgm/4/
Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does :before not work on img tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-tags)

Answer (score 3):

`<img>` is one of these elements on which [we can't apply `:before` and `:after` because it has no content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-input-elements/4574946#4574946) due to the `<img>` tag being self-closing (in other words no closing tag)

Answer (score 1):

img element does not support pseudo elements

Comment: It does... but there's no `figure` element in OP question so?

Comment: What I mean is that img element

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to give as well a real height.
100% of no height in parent gives 100% of nothing (cascade/inheritance).
give `position:relative` to element `.body` and
size you `absolute` pseudo-element on `.body` with:

```
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
```