# How to give red line before the text box in html?

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML. How can i give a red line before the text box as in screen shot?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: A red line before the input? What does your HTML look like? What have you tried? That is basic HTML / CSS.

Comment: Use [CSS](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/).

Comment: You can put and element in the red place or put the input field inside the container with a little more width and float the input to right.But >>>> The easiest ways is to make the left border of the input wider and colored.

Comment: A related note: css `:before` `:after` won't work with input eleemnts. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4574912/1273830

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is plenty ways, one of them is to place the input inside of a div and then style it with CSS.

Here is an example:

```
<div style="border-left: 2px solid red; padding-left: 2px;">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

And here you can see how it looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/r9MZN/

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this :

here is a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/manishkumarshr/MQkha/)

```
<div id="blc"><span>&nbsp;</span><input  type="text"/></div>

#blc span {
    border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`border-left`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-left.asp) css property

Answer (score 1):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n7c8H/1/

html:

```
<div class="red-border-left">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.red-border-left {
    border-left: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS pseudo selector :before but since it doesn't work for Input elements, you need to look for other options,

E-g Insert a span before the input element and use pseudo selector on that. e-g:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    span:after{

      content:"";
      border:1px solid red;
      margin-right:5px;

      }
  </style>


  </head>

  <body>
     <span></span><input type="text" id="ttt" />
  </body>

</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/i5pbRAbHbJkWLSD0OuYQ?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Its like this one:

```
<div class="redline"><input type="text" /></div>
```

For the css:

```
.redline {
border-left: #hexcode;
}
```