# css content property using :after

Tags: css

I have a problem, I have this input text fields in a html form, this are wrapped for this `div` css properties:

`.formRight240 { float: left; width: 240px; margin: 5px 12px 5px 0px; }`

when I try to this

```
.field_required{ display: inline; color: red; } 
.field_required:after{ content: "*" }
```

the input text field stay the same and the asterisk jump to the next line, I know the reason, everything is aligned in order to the other elements around, but is there anything I can do to display the asterisk inline with the input text field by doing changes to the `field_required` class? if not, what I have to change to the `.formRight240.`

**HTML**

```
<div class="rowElem noborder">
    <label>Customer ID:</label>
    <div class="formRight240">
        <span class="field_required"><input type="text" name="p_cust_id_c" id="req" class="validate[required,maxSize[30]]"/></span>
    </div>
    <div class="fix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without html markups, i won't be able to help you further except for writing this : float-right, fixed-width, inline-elements, adding to the right ... Incoming headache.

Comment: Dear newUser, please, move your html code from your comment to add it within your question.

Comment: I am sorry I am new on this web site XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574946/1930721), you can't add :before or :after to an input.

A solution could be to wrap your input in a span:

HTML

```
<span class="field_required"><input type="text" /><span>
```

CSS

```
.field_required input {
    display: inline;
    color: red;
} 
.field_required:after{ 
    content: "*";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/myWeE/)

Comment: I just try it but, is not working, here is the line of my input type <span class="field_required"><input type="text" name="p_cust_id_c" id="req" class="validate[required,maxSize[30]]"/></span>

Comment: yes but i think the problem is this, .formRight240 { float: left; width: 240px; margin: 5px 12px 5px 0px; }, do you think that may be this wrapper is making the aterisk jump just below the input type?

Comment: This is the HTML 
<div class="rowElem noborder"><label>Customer ID:</label>
   <div class="formRight240">
<span class="field_required"><input type="text" name="p_cust_id_c" id="req" class="validate[required,maxSize[30]]"/></span>
   </div><div class="fix"></div>
  </div>

Comment: Still works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/myWeE/2/ , still the asterix is after the input. You need to check the rest of your code...

Comment: ok fixed, this is how I had to pud the span tag  

--

<span class="field_required"> <div class="formRight240">

<input type="text" name="p_cust_id_c" id="req" class="validate[required,maxSize[30]]" value=""/>

<input type="text" name="p_cust_id_c" id="req" class="validate[required,maxSize[30]]"/>

</div></span>