# plus sign in html input type=number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anyone know if it's possible to add a plus sign in a html input type=number field? I have a scenario whereby users need to enter a modifier value which is either  +1 to +10 or -1 to -10. I want to make it very explicit to the user that their inputted value increments the resulting value. therefore it would be great if a + sign is prepended to a positive inputted value.

I'm using this input in an Angular2 reactive form with bootstrap styling. so an Angular2 directive, a boostrap style or even a jquery solution are welcome

What I've seen so far is about adding currency symbols inside the form control or about adding + and minus buttons to increment and decrement the value. But that's not what I want, so I doubt if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to manipulate the input.
The default behavior is "-" for negative and no sign for positive numbers.

Even if you checked some custom UI frameworks like:
JQuery UI, Bootstrap, Angular Material ... you will not get the wished behavior.

I guess the only solution for this is to write your own custom code.

Two scenarios are possible:

**1-** An input with Text and the manipulating will be done in Javascript.

**2-** Create a pipe in angular2 and give it to the element which I think is much easier than the first one.

Comment: Thanks! To use a pipe is indeed a good suggestion which I hadn't thought off so far. Will mark this one as answer

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible. The number field only accepts `-`, `0-9` and `e` to be entered. As a workaround you could place the `+` in the HTML before the input, eg:

```html
+ <input type="number" />
```

Alternatively you could use a standard `type="text"` input, but that would mean creating your own validation logic which would make the code much more complex.

Comment: Apart from a JavaScript workaround that may cause a number of issues, this is the best method.

Answer (score -3):

I hope this will help on you guys!!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on('keypress','#input',function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.which;

    if ($(this).val().trim().charAt(0) == "\u002B") {
       if (  keyCode == 43 ) { 
          return false;
       }
    }
    else{
       for (var i = 1; i < $(this).val().length+1; i++) {
          if(i!=0){
             if (  keyCode == 43 ) { 
                return false;
             }
          }
       }
     }
  });

  $(document).on('input', '#input', function() {
     this.value = this.value.replace(/[^+{1}|^0-9]/g,'');
  });
</script>
```