# CSS before counter not working on div

Tags: html, css, css-content

I'm having trouble displaying content before input element.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9UC93nnNm6vmmLEIYDJK?p=preview

On this plunker you can see `input:before` should display something, but it's not displaying anything

1) If I change it to `p:before` it displays content before `p`, but without incremented value, what should I change there?

2) Why it doesn't display values for `input:before`?

**[EDIT after Daniels's and dTDesign's answers/comments]**

@dTDesign

I changed it to `p`, it adds content now and with combination of @Daniel's answer (I changed .main to main) I got displaying content in front of paragraphs with correct incrementing.

so you can use main within HTML5.

### Update:

It works fine now:

Comment: For your question #2 take a look to the answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-input-elements

Comment: You should be posting comments down here instead of putting your replies in an edit.

Comment: For user with reputation below 10 I had to wait 8 hours to reply on my own issue. I think it's better for people to get answers right away, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you need to put `counter-reset: input_counter;` in a parent element (for example the body) to initiate it. Right now you try to do this on `.main`, but from what I can see, such element doesn't exist (you do have a tag named `main`, but that's an entirely different thing).

Edit: Sorry, I'm obviously not accustomed enough with HTML5. `<main>` is very much an accepted tag in HTML5. :)

Comment: Ah, I missed that I used class in CSS, I've changed that, BUT isn't main HTML5 element? And, when I change it in css to main, it still doesn't help