# How to add a text after input text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add "month" after the input in bootstrap, in the side of it. 
I've tried `span`, `pull-left` nothing worked. `Months` is always below

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Months</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" style="width: 50%" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Months"> months
</div>
</form>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7rYp7/)

Comment: You would need to wrap 'month` with a tag in order to manipulate it.

Comment: don't forget to select an answer :)

Comment: Related: [How to add text before input element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557615/how-to-add-text-before-input-element-using-javascript), [How to put text in front of the input form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781178/how-to-put-text-in-front-of-the-input-form) and [CSS content generation before or after 'input' elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-or-after-input-elements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `form-inline` to your form..

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Months</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" style="width: 50%" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Months"> months
    </div>
</form>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/119625

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the elements and specifying the column widths:

**HTML**

```
 <form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="pull-left col-xs-9">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
     </div>
    <span class="col-xs-3">months<span>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
span{
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7rYp7/2/

Comment: doesn't work. The "label" has moved for the left of input. This is above of it

Answer (score 1):

putting `style="display:inline"` into the actual input element in question has worked for me.

Listen, I know we are supposed to avoid using `style` and only use classes defined in CSS but I tried all the example above and this is the only thing that worked.

Comment: I can confirm this works. When using Bootstrap, you can use the class ```.d-inline```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following in your CSS (overwriting the bootstrap.css)

```
.form-group input {
    display:inline;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

You can also use a different selector to be more specific (instead of overwriting it for all inputs) **UPDATED**:

```
#exampleInputEmail1{
        display:inline;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 5px;
}

.form-group label {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I see, you want the label to stay on top of the input and the 'month' still next to the input.  Did I understand it right?

Comment: ok, you can use Kevin's method or the code in the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/7rYp7/4/