# How to put text in front of the input form?

Tags: html, css, forms, input

Whenever I use input forms in html , I do it for example like this:

```
<form>
  First name:<input type="text" name="firstname">
  </form>.
```

So, this will make it like this : First name and then input field below "first name" text. How do I make it so that it's like in this case:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDGzD.png

Basically, "First name" and then input RIGHT NEXT to it? I am using HTML 5 and CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use tables like this :)

```html
<form>
   <table>
      <tr>
          <td>First name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>last name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: top;" >Message </td>
          <td><textarea></textarea></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
 </form>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put label tag,

```
<form>
  <label>First name: </label> <input type="text" name="firstname">
</form>
```

For multiple form field add parent div for each of them like below code

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label>First name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Second name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="secondname">
  </div>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use table to do it without any complex styling in css. So it will looks like this:

```
<form>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td<input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

But you can also use label tag :

```
<label for="firstname">First Name :/label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
```

or styling in css with float funtion