# How to add text before input element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

```
 item1:<input type="text" name="item1">
```

**I want to add the text "item1" before the input element in JavaScript.How can I do that?**

I have created an input tag in JavaScript using

```
var i1 =document.createElement("input");
```

Comment: Do you mean in the markup or you want to approach this using javascript?

Comment: Look at [these resources](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp) by w3school

Comment: Use `input.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin, 'HTML')`. MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: This is possibly a repeated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554149/html-javascript-change-div-content).

Comment: I have updated the question. Please do check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

```js
document.querySelector('input').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', "item1: ");
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item1">
```

If you are creating the element dynamically, first append it to an element like the body, and then use `insertAdjacentHTML`.

```js
var i1 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(i1)
i1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', "Item: ");
```

Comment: var i1 =document.createElement("input"); I'm new to this. can you explain me more how can i do this?

Comment: @JainishDabhi You can do this: `document.body.appendChild(i1);
i1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', "Item: ");`

Answer (score 0):

Use `input.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', 'HTML')`. This code inserts HTML before the start of the input element.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
input.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', 'item1: ')
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item1">
```

MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: index.html:195 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertAdjacentHTML' on 'Element': The element has no parent.

Comment: Are you using `document.createElement()`? I’ve only seen that error with `document.createElement()`. It’s happening because you haven’t appended the element to anything.

Comment: Yes. I have created an Input element by using document.createElement()

Comment: Then use `element.appendChild(input)` before using `insertAdjacentHTML`

Comment: var i1 =document.createElement("input"); I kind of new to this. can you explain me more how can i do this?

Comment: If you're appending it directly to the document, use `document.body.appendChild(i1)`. Else use `element.appendChild(i1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This code finds all the `input` in the document with `name` attributes and prepends the `name` text in front of the `input`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[name]").forEach((input) => {
  input.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', `${input.name}: `);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item1"><br>
<input type="text" name="item2"><br>
<input type="text" name="item3">
```

Comment: var i1 =document.createElement("input"); I'm new to this. can you explain me more how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element, like this

```
let input = document.querySelector("input")
let element = document.createElement("YOUR DESIRED ELEMENT GOES HERE")
element.insertBefore(input)
```

Comment: index.html:195 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('YOUR DESIRED ELEMENT GOES HERE') is not a valid name.