# Why doesn't my image show :before my text input?

Tags: html, css

I want an image right before my text input. I'm trying :before with no luck or sign of the image!

http://jsfiddle.net/4U9uW/

```
<input type="text" class="form-control vrm-input" id="vrm" name="vrm" placeholder="" maxlength="10">

.vrm-input:before {
    background: url("http://www.byplug.com/oink.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: " ";
    height: 112px;
    left: -61px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 61px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I'm sure it's simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` elements have no 'content', they are not like divs,p,span: `<div>here goes ::before content ::after</div>`

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574946/1666071 for more info.

Comment: Arh thanks! I've wrapped it in a div and all working. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use **:before** selector with **`<input>`** element, you should use outside **`<div>`** element,

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4U9uW/5/)**</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<div class="vrm-input">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vrm" name="vrm" placeholder="" maxlength="10" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.vrm-input:before {
    content: url("http://www.byplug.com/oink.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 112px;
    left: -10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 61px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```