# Angularjs required asteriks

Tags: angularjs

I'd have a directives with a large form with some fields that are required and some that are not. The required fields are marked with `required` attribute.

I want to pre-pend all the inputs with `<span class='something'>*</span>`
Basically something like this: `$("input[required]").prepend(<span class='something'>*</span>)`

My still limited understanding of angularjs points me to the compile function of my directives but I am lost when I get there.

Disclaimer: my gut feeling is telling me that doing something like that is not really "the angular" way - that's ok, regardless of whether I end up using this technique or not I'd like to know how to do that. That said I welcome more "angular" suggestions as well.

Thank you!

Comment: How is the required attribute being added to the inputs?

Comment: Declaratively. It's in the HTML of the directive.

Comment: Right, but it's not being dynamically added? If it's not dynamic, you already know which fields are required and thus can add the `*` where you add the `required` attribute. If it is dynamic, then I'm wanting to know how they are being dynamically added.

Comment: No they are not dynamically added, you are right I could just go and add the asterisk myself. I don't want to do that. I'd like to work so the act of marking something `required` makes the asterisk appear automatically

Comment: Ok, I get where you're coming from, answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever DOM manipulation enters the conversation, a directive is the way to go. You're wanting to prepend a `*` to any inputs with a `required` attribute, so you want to create a directive from the required attribute. Something like this:

```
myModule.directive("required", function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'A', //only want it triggered for attributes
       compile: function(element) {
          //could add a check to make sure it's an input element if need be
           element.prepend("<span class='something'>*</span>");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Neat! And angular-y. Thank you.

Comment: This does not seem to work in `<input >` , however works fine on a `<div>`. Please advise.

Comment: Not sure why that would make a difference. Put a fiddle together that reproduces the problem, and I could take a look.

Comment: Looks like for input you need `.after` and `.before` instead of `.prepend` and `.append`. Don't know why yet.

Comment: @americanslon, it doesn't work for input because input elements have no content. Even if you manually write `<input>Something Here</input>`, the browser will ignore the contents.  `.append()` and `.prepend()` both insert contents *inside* the current element, so won't work for inputs.  Same reason why [`input:before` doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4574946/1366033).  As you noted, you should be fine using `.after()` instead. Although [.before() will create an infinity loop](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5663)

Answer (score 2):

```
input[required], select[required] {
    background-image: url('/img/star.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
```

Image has some 20px space on the right not to overlap with select dropdown arrow

[image: Image is here]

Answer (score 0):

```
committeeApp.directive("requiredStar", function ($compile) { 
return { 
    restrict: 'AE', 
    require: "^form", 
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) { 
        var varName = ctrl.$name + "." + attrs.name + ".$error.required";           
        var a_input = angular.element($compile('<span style="color:red;" ng-show="' + varName + '" >&#10033;</span>')(scope)); 
        element.parent().prepend(a_input); 
    } 
};
```