# Use glyphicon to mark required field with css

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In our Angularjs Application, we set the required Fields dynamically (ng-required). Therefore it is a quite complicated to add an `*` to the label every time it is required.

Now we have another idea. It may be possible to mark the input-field itself as required. In [this post](http://skybeam.de/blog/html5-input-required/), we found a part of the solution.

There were CSS-Selectors for a required field, so we can set a Background-Image for that like this:

```css
input:required:valid {
  background-image: url(valid.png);
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
input:required:invalid {
  background-image: url(invalid.png);
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Name:</p>
<input type="text" name="name" required />
```

But using that way, we need a background image of an `*`, And this seems to be very hacky. Especially, if there are different Sizes of the form, so the Image has different resolutions.

Than we found [this (Section Labeled)](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/input.html) example and it seems to be possible to add Text to the input field.

So the question is, how can I put that all together, so that I can put an glyphicon from twitter-bootstrap to the right side of an input field, if that is required without editing all my forms?

Hers a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnr41xat/2/). That might work, but the problem is, that background-size is not [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) everywhere.

Comment: This was already answered here: [Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box/18839305#18839305)

Comment: The whole question here is: "because it is *quite complicated*... we are trying something else". What was the complication that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: @CarlosMan: Thanks for the answer, but then I have to edit all my forms. With a CSS-Class it may be possible to add the * without editing all the forms.

Comment: The answer reference above would work well for your use case if you make one of the options presented (***"With Bootstrap"***, for instance) into a directive that would produce the ***form-group*** for you. That way you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @CarlosMan: Thats something I can think about, but I also have to edit all my forms. But if I chose the directive solution, how do I add the glyphicon only if the field is required?

Comment: @NewDev We have some Fields that are requred and some that are not required. But in some cases the required Attribute is set by AngularJS, so I could not allwas add a hardcoded * to our Lables. So I want to do it via CSS to avoid to edit all my forms and to avoid the runtime of JS (wich might not be as much)

Comment: Setting an attribute of the directive as a conditional and using said conditional in the ***ng-show*** or ***ng-if*** (depending on these templates being dinamically-compiled or not)  of the tag containing your glyphicon or fontawesome icon (<i> or <span>, etc.).

Comment: I will go with Carlos Man solution OR you can just make and actual markup of <span class="asterisk">*</span> then set displayt to none and for the css of the input try using a sibling selector "~" to trigger display: visible of asterisk when needed. (ie.  input:required:invalid ~ .asterisk { display: visible };)

Comment: I added a jsFiddle. I hope it helps...

@gsalisi CarlosMan That is all something where I have to edit my Markup (which has a lot of input Fields). So that is only a fallback solutions, but it is one i can think about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs required asteriks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275915/angularjs-required-asteriks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Option 1

As mentioned in [Angularjs required asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23275915/1366033), you can add a directive for the required attribute like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('stack', []);

app.directive("required", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // only for attributes
        compile: function(element) {
            // insert asterisk after elment 
            element.after("<span class='required'>*</span>");
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.required {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.11/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="stack">
  
  <input type="text" required />
  
</div>
```

### Option 2

As mentioned in [Use CSS to automatically add 'required field' asterisk to form inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11197671/1366033), using background image is perfectly fine also:

```css
input[required], 
select[required]{
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/zEIWMh4.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 45px;
}
```

```html
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" required /><br/>
```

> **Note**: You *cannot* use [`input:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to create a pseudo element after input because `:before` and `:after` ["are rendered are within the container itself as a child element and `input` can not contain other elements hence it's not supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/1366033)