# AngularJS: How to know if input text in form is required or not in Controller JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm Using AngularJS, I have a need that to know whether control within the form is required or not. So that i can append the label above the control with * symbol.

I have seen solutions like below:
[Angularjs required asteriks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275915/angularjs-required-asteriks)

But in my case i need it for label above to it and also Not all controls are basic controls i have used plugin's like ui-select and many more.

> Result:

As we have in-built isEmpty() or $dirty functions in angularjs

```
formName.TextBoxControlName.$dirty => true/false;
```

can i have function/property included in angularjs saying that isRequired (returns boolean)

```
formName.TextBoxControlName.$isRequired => true/false;
```

im expecting is it possible to have a new property to control itself like (isRequired) so that no matter what the scenario is, i can use that property for that control to set the asterisk symbol.

in HTML:

```
(label) {{formName.TextBoxControlName.isRequired}}
```

in JS:

```
$scope.star function (){
    return $scope.formName.TextBoxControlName.isrequired ? '*' : ''
    }
```

**[Edit]**

I'm Updating with Scenarios in below:

> Direct Scenario

is, I have many textboxes in form with

```
required="textboxName" (if NOT required).
required="!textboxName" (if required).
```

> Indirect Scenario 1:

```
label{*}        (label)
[________]      (textbox)
```

the input text is by default not mandatory (so NO asterisk symbol).

```
required="textboxName"
```

but on some condition i making it required (so Need asterisk symbol) as below:

```
$scope.formName.TextBoxControlName.$setValidity('required', false);
```

> Indirect Scenario 2:

```
label{*}             (label)
[________] [x]       (textbox)(checkbox)
```

the input text is by default not mandatory (so NO asterisk symbol) But on checkbox true it is mandatory (so Need asterisk symbol).

```
required="checkboxName"
```

Now how can i maintain asterisk symbol for my scenario's in HTML page itself (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function ExampleController($scope) {
  $scope.isRequired = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="form">
      <label for="required">Toggle required:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isRequired" id="required" />
      <br>
      <label for="input">Label</label><span ng-show="isRequired">*</span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-required="isRequired" />
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

You could simply use [ngRequired](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired)...
See code snippet (based on official docs).

Comment: Hi MacroS, i'm giving required by default for some fields but for some on condition, this is okay if conditionally but for initially required they need to show * when made optional * must be gone.

Comment: Reduced the text in question for you

Comment: I'm sorry, I really can't fully grasp your question... :-(

Comment: Hi MarcoS, i have reduced much more content, Only read Result block which is output im expecting

Answer (score 0):

For validate your form You can use `myForm.$valid` and `myForm.input.$error.required`.
you can find in documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

For show * when form is invalid:

```
input: <input name="input" ng-model="test.test" required>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">*</span><br>
```

And for prevent submit you can Use `ng-submit`

```
<form name ="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="myForm.$valid && myForm.submit()">
```

P.S. `novalidate` is for prevent a native validation.

Comment: Hi LorenzoBerti, by showing controls to user itself i need * to be displayed, BUT myForm.input.$error.required will be there only if form is submitted and form is not valid

Comment: Yes, you can wrap <span> on ng show.
I will edit my answer

Comment: On pageload how can i show page as dirty to user? i need them on page load and then act according to required/optional conditions

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand, you want know if form is dirty or pristine or you want send submit form and return with error?