# content not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

Content not working in firefox..working beautifully in chrome what is the problem?
please check and say as soon as possible.

This is HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
     </head>
    <body>
      <input class="go" type="checkbox">
    </body>
</html>
```

This is CSS Part

```
.go {


    top: 5px;
        left: 150px;

        position: relative;
        margin: 35px auto;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        font-size: 1.0em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .go:before {
        top: -5px;
        left: -50px;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;

        width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #76011b;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background: linear-gradient(red, blue); 
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(19,93,158,.6);
        content: "Launch";
    }
```

/*content in here not working in firefox */

```
    .go:checked:after {
        background: linear-gradient(red, blue); 
        content: "Relaunch";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vendor prefixes for the linear gradient needs to be added:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(red, blue); /* Standard syntax */
```

Comment: `linear-gradient(red, blue)` works just fine in Firefox without a vendor prefix.

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudo-elements :after and :before doesn't work on input elements (and on img element by the way)**. Because, actually, they are not supposed to have any content.

You'll have to wrap this input :

```
<span class="go"><input type="checkbox"></span>
```

Comment: I think it's because your :before pseudo-element is covering your checkbox. And well, in my Chrome, this is not working too. Your code is not standard, you probably should achieve this with some JS.

Comment: Here is my code in js fiddle...look how beautifully it works---http://jsfiddle.net/6qmzjsvj/

Comment: Your example works in Chrome, even if it's not supposed too. If you want a cross browser solution, change the HTML as I suggested and handle it with some JS. It will never works in Firefox, because it's not standard. See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-input-elements#answer-4574946