# IE10 can't support :after/:before when the element is "input type='radio'"?

Tags: javascript, css, html

here is my demo

http://jsfiddle.net/JingXiao/2k3eba6w/

```
<input type="radio" class="testRadio" value="All"  data="helloworld"></input>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="testRadio" value="All"  data="helloworld"></input>
```

it works in chrome and safari, but not work in IE or ff. Or any other solution to achieve in IE/ff?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/2k3eba6w/1/

Comment: The before and after pseudo classes are valid with container elements like div, span, article, etc. Since radio does not contain any other elements in it, before/after doesn't work.

Comment: @MelanciaUK It's an invalid HTML. input is self closing element

Comment: Answer is given here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-input-elements

Comment: @Dipaks Thanks, i am puzzled with why chrome/safari seems support it.

Comment: @kingswang Seems they are spoiling the devs :)

Comment: @Dipaks It was early morning I didn't notice that. :)

Comment: @MelanciaUK That's ok :) Coffee? LOL :)