# CSS pseudo selector before with content does not work on html input tag

Tags: html, css

I need to display some text before and after the `input` tag using CSS `content`.

Using the following code I am not able to obtain the desired effect on the `input` tag, but works fine of `a` tag.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/pgdu2tue/1/

```
<input id="test" type="text" name="nametest">

<br>
<a id="moz" href="http://www.mozilla.org/">Mozilla Home Page</a>

#moz::before {
    content:"XXX" ;
}
#test::before {
    content:"BEFORE" ;
}
#test::after {
    content:"AFTER" ;
}
```

Comment: You can't add :pseudo-elements to an `input` element.

Comment: as chipChocolate.py said, you can't use pseudo elements on empty elements, i.e. img input br etc, anything without a closing tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS content generation before 'input' elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-input-elements)

Comment: @Gibbok - added answer below with detail, this is not 'technically' due to `input` having no content per-se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't insert content before or after using ::befoer & ::after because there is no content in an input tag.  Read a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-input-elements)

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to `input` tags not having any content per-se.

`input` elements are a special type called **[`replaced elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)**, these do not support `:psuedo` selectors, as they are outside the scope of CSS.

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element **whose representation is
>   outside the scope of CSS**. These are kind of external objects whose
>   representation is independent of the CSS. Typical replaced elements
>   are `<img>`, `<object>`, `<video>` or form elements like `<textarea>`
>   and `<input>`. Some elements, like  or `<canvas>` are replaced
>   elements only in specific cases. Objects inserted using the CSS
>   content properties are anonymous replaced elements.

Note that this is even referred to [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content)

> This specification does not fully define the interaction of `:before`
>   and `:after` with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML).