# ::before with input in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, pseudo-element

I'm trying to put some content before an input tag using CSS pseudo-class **::before**. It works in Chrome but not in Firefox. What seems to be the problem with Firefox?

Here's a snippet:

```css
input::before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 13px;
 height: 13px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #9F0002 inset;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="radio" value="male">male
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="radio" value="female">female
```

...and here's the outcome. Chrome works just fine:

[image]

but there are **no changes in Firefox**:

[image]

Comment: This is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-or-after-input-elements

Comment: This would be even better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/2003702

Comment: Well if you want to have the red rings around the inputs try adding a `span` and put the before on that

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I'll try using an extra span.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content).

> Authors specify the style and location of generated content with the :before and :after pseudo-elements. As their names indicate, the :before and :after pseudo-elements specify the location of content before and after an element's document tree content. The 'content' property, in conjunction with these pseudo-elements, specifies what is inserted.

`:before` and `:after` should only work on the element which can act as a container of content. `<input>` cannot contain any content so it should not support those pseudo-elements. Chrome supports because it does not follow the spec (or bug?).

Comment: In other words, Chrome plays by its own rules. Thanks for this info!

Comment: Interesting that Safari copies chrome on this one and displays pseudo elements for inputs.

Comment: @Levidps this issue may come rom Webkit, Chrome's engine is forked from Webkit