# How to add FontAwesome icon to submit button in Wordpress using ContactForm7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to add fontawesome arrow icon to submit button in Wordpress using ContactForm7. I have this:
[submit class:button "Send a message "]
in css:

```
.wpcf7-submit:before {
    content: '\f30b';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free' !important;
}
```

And it doesnt work, any ideas?

Comment: Are there any other CSS rules for `.wpcf7-submit:before` (in Chrome: Inspect > Styles)?

Comment: there are not any other css rules for this

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block;` to your rules and see if it helps.

Comment: doesnt work. i am importing font awesome from     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
and is for this link good font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free' ?

Comment: Have a look at the answer below. If it helped, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I've just found an easier option (or at least I thought so!) that helped me get an icon on my submit button.

No pseudo elements needed, you can just insert the element straight into the Contact Form:

```html
<!--add the following instead of [submit] in Contact Form 7-->
<button type="submit" class="wpcf7-submit">Send Message<i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
<img class="ajax-loader" src="/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 1;">
```

You can also then add styles to the button like this:

```css
/*Then you can add whatever style you want to your button*/

button.wpcf7-submit {
  background: #31D1D3;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 0;
}

button.wpcf7-submit i {
  margin-left: 5px
}

button.wpcf7-submit:hover {
  color: white;
}

button.wpcf7-submit:hover i {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<!--just for this example, presume you already have font awesome installed if you're looking to output a button-->


<!--add the following instead of [submit] in Contact Form 7-->

<button type="submit" class="btn primary wpcf7-submit">Send Message<i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
<img class="ajax-loader" src="/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 1;">
```

### Update:

You can even use Font Awesome Ajax Loader instead of the CF7 one!

```css
/*Then you can add whatever style you want to your button*/

button.wpcf7-submit {
  background: #31D1D3;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 0;
}

button.wpcf7-submit i {
  margin-left: 5px
}

button.wpcf7-submit:hover {
  color: white;
}

button.wpcf7-submit:hover i {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<!--just for this example, presume you already have font awesome installed if you're looking to output a button-->


<!--add the following instead of [submit] in Contact Form 7-->

<button type="submit" class="btn primary wpcf7-submit">Send Message<i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
<i class="fab fa-github ajax-loader" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 1;"></i>
```

Comment: It seems that the current version of CF7 (5.4.2) adds the ajax-loader automatically even if you hardcode the button with a <button> tag. No need to add the <img> ajax-loader manually.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Contact Form 7 by default uses an `<input type="submit">` element for the submit button. `input` elements can't use the ::before/::after pseudo elements because [`input` elements don't have child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27708091/9131961).

You'll need to change your submit button into an actual button (as shown [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/submit-button-instead-of-inputtypesubmit/)) for you to be able to add FontAwesome icons to it.

---

You also need to specify the `font-weight` property, otherwise the font won't be loaded by the browser.

```css
.wpcf7-submit::before {
    content: "\f30b";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="" method="post">
  <button type="submit" class="wpcf7-submit">
    Send
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for response but it doesnt work. Wordpress ContactForm7 generate not a button but input type=submit.

Comment: You're right. `input` doesn't have child nodes so `::before` and `::after` can't be applied to it. Edit your contact form and change the `<input type="submit">` button into an actual button and it'll work ([example](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/submit-button-instead-of-inputtypesubmit/)).