# Apply style from Bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, jsf, bootstrap-4, jsf-2

I have this JSF code which I use to create table pagination table:

```
<h:commandButton 
  value="first"
  action="#{registeredAttendies.pageFirst}"
  disabled="#{registeredAttendies.firstRow == 0}" 
  styleClass="icon icon-xs icon-default mdi mdi-arrow-left-bold"
>
  <f:ajax render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
........
```

I would like to apply Bootstrap style for this JSF code but the result is not looking good:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="pagination-classic">
    <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-xs icon-default mdi mdi-arrow-left-bold"></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-xs mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold"></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried to use:

```
<h:commandButton value="first"
  action="#{registeredAttendies.pageFirst}"
  disabled="#{registeredAttendies.firstRow == 0}" 
  styleClass="icon icon-xs icon-default mdi mdi-arrow-left-bold"
>
  <f:ajax render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

But the result is not good for some reason.
Do you know how I can apply the style properly?

Comment: Style is applied to HTML, not to JSF. The JSF code you posted has in no way a relation to JSF.

Answer (score 1):

While the description of your exact problem

> the result is not good for some reason

leaves much to the imagination I am guessing it is related to the `h:commandButton` being rendered as an html `input` element, which [does not work with `:before` and `:after`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574946/11663146) pseudo classes, which is what for example mdi will use to apply the desired icons. As described in the linked answer, a possible solution could be to wrap the generated input element in some sort of container (e.g. `span` or `div`) and apply the desired styles to that element.

Comment: The description of all questions (> 1400!!!) by this poster leave a lot to the imagination. it seems this poster refuses to learn the basics about technology and stackoverflow